# Is it possible to optimize ML models further and get better R2 score than the one suggested by lazypredict?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm using lazypredict in Jupyter Notebook. It automatically run different ML models and sort the R^2 score result of them in a form of table so that one can realize which models perform the best. I'm wondering if we can optimize the best performing model by hyperparameter tuning and get a better R^2 score than the one suggested by lazypredict.

I searched a lot about this but couldn't find any relevant result.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for lazypredict is pretty minimal, but it doesn't appear to do any sort of hyperparameter tuning whatsoever, due to the nature of what it's doing you can't even specify hyperparameters. So my recommendation would be to take the top 3-5 models that it finds and do either manual hyperparameter tuning or a grid search.